# $compile error in bundled angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Here is unbundled angular code which is working well.

```
angular.module('XXX').directive('xxx', ['$compile', '$injector', function($compile, $injector){
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: false,
   transclude: true,
  ...
  XXX.attachEvent("XXX", function(id){
   angular.element(document.querySelector( '[name="isallday"]' )).attr('ng-model', 'isallday');  
   angular.element( document.querySelector( ".dhx_section_time" )
            .getElementsByTagName("select") ).attr('ng-class', '{dhx_time_disable: isallday}').attr('ng-disabled', 'isallday');
   var el = angular.element(document.querySelector( ".dhx_cal_larea" ));    
   $injector = el.injector();
   $injector.invoke(function($compile){
      $compile(el)($scope)
   }) 
  })
}
}]);
```

I added ng-model dynamically not statically.
But when I run this code in bundled environment,
it displays an error.

> uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%203C-%20t

My project use asp.net and angularjs and dhx.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: What are the libraries do you included in HTML view? Can you share it here?

Comment: I am using dhx schedule.
So I add ng-modal when displays a newEvent dialog.

Comment: Try to change with angular version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue probably is minification/uglification among these lines:

```
$injector.invoke(function($compile){
  $compile(el)($scope)
})
```

When the invoked function gets minified/uglified, its first parameter `$compile` is renamed to `t` in your case resulting in the unknown `tProvider` error. Try the following:

```
$injector.invoke(['$compile', function($compile){
  $compile(el)($scope)
}])
```

(or reuse the `$compile` you injected in your directive...)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I followed your guide and fixed it.